# Computer is steady on high memory usage not showing what takes up the memory

Tags: windows-10, memory

Windows 10 here, I have 8GB on my machine.
[image]

[image]

Clearly, task manager thinks otherwise (about 1600MB acounts for 70%. that's wrong).

When looking at computer's properties, i do see 8GB.

Where do I find my missing ram?

Computer is extremely slow.

Running malware bytes anti malware found nothing.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Performance tab of Task Manager on the Memory page/tab?

Comment: If you toggle each of those reveal > arrows to the left you will see child processes - you need to add those up, the 'global' figure you see for instance next to Firefox is only the memory used by the app itself, each open page/tab will be using additional memory.

Comment: @HelpingHand edited with the requested picture. Thanks!

Comment: @Tetsujin No, when I show all sub tasks, they all add up to what the main task shows. All the tabs together take up 770.9MB in the abovew image.

Comment: @Gulzar Non-paged pool at 1.2GB seems pretty high.  If you restart the computer and check that same value, what is it?  How quickly does it climb to over 1 GB.  Seems to me you probably have a driver with a memory leak. I would suggest running Poolmon to hopefully give you the pool tag of the driver that is allocating memory that perhaps isn't freeing it.  Search for Poolmon and kernel memory leak.